# My CASE statement is wrong. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am in a logjam.

When I run the following query, it works:

```
 select DISTINCT l.Seating_Capacity - (select count(*)
                        from tblTrainings t1, tbllocations l
                        where l.locationId = t1.LocationId) as
                        availableSeats
                        from tblTrainings t1, tbllocations l
                        where l.locationId = t1.LocationId
```

However, we would like to add a CASE statement that says, when Seating_Capacity - total count as shown above = 0 then show 'FULL' message.

Otherwise, show remaining number.

Here is that query:

```
                 select DISTINCT case when l.Seating_Capacity - (select count(*)
                from tblTrainings t1, tbllocations l
                where l.locationId = t1.LocationId) = 0 then 'full' else STR(Seating_Capacity) end)
                availableSeats
                from tblTrainings t1, tbllocations l
                where l.locationId = t1.LocationId
```

I am getting 'Incorrect syntax near ')' which is near 'End'

I am also getting an error that the inner Seating_Capacity is invalid column name.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

I must have been in a dream land because I thought it was working during testing.

Now, the app is live and it isn't working.

Thanks a lot in advance

```
select DISTINCT l.LocationId,c.courseId, c.coursename, l.Seating_Capacity - (select count(*)
                        from tblTrainings t1
                        where l.locationId = t1.LocationId and c.courseId = t1.courseId) as
                        availableSeats,d.dateid,d.trainingDates,d.trainingtime,c.CourseDescription,
                        i.instructorName,l.location,l.seating_capacity 
                        from tblLocations l
                        Inner Join tblCourses c on l.locationId = c.locationId
                        left join tblTrainings t on l.locationId = t.LocationId and c.courseId = t.courseId
                        Inner Join tblTrainingDates d on c.dateid=d.dateid 
                        Inner Join tblCourseInstructor ic on c.courseId = ic.CourseId  
                        Inner Join tblInstructors i on ic.instructorId = i.instructorId
                        WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.trainingDates, 101) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
```

Comment: remoce `)` after `END` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the query with your subquery. As I understand it then the following should work as you need:

```
SELECT  AvailableSeats = CASE WHEN l.Seating_Capacity - COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'Full' 
                            ELSE STR(l.Seating_Capacity - COUNT(*)) 
                        END
FROM    tblTrainings t1
        INNER JOIN tblLocations l
            ON l.LocationID = t1.LocationID
GROUP BY l.Seating_Capacity;
```

I have changed your else to `STR(l.Seating_Capacity - COUNT(*))` because I assume you want to know the seats remaining, rather than just the capacity? If I have misinterpreted the requirement, just change it to `STR(l.Seating_Capacity)`.

I have also switched your ANSI 89 implicit joins to ANSI 92 explicit joins, the standard changed over 20 years, and there are [plenty of good reasons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to switch to the newer syntax. But for completeness the ANSI 89 version of the above query would be:

```
SELECT  AvailableSeats = CASE WHEN l.Seating_Capacity - COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'Full' 
                            ELSE STR(l.Seating_Capacity - COUNT(*)) 
                        END
FROM    tblTrainings t1, tblLocations l
WHERE   l.LocationID = t1.LocationID
GROUP BY l.Seating_Capacity;
```

---

**EDIT**

To adapt your full query you can simply replace your subquery in the select, with a joined subquery:

```
SELECT  l.LocationId,
        c.courseId, 
        c.coursename, 
        CASE WHEN l.Seating_Capacity - t.SeatsTaken = 0 THEN 'Full' 
            ELSE STR(l.Seating_Capacity - t.SeatsTaken) 
            END AS availableSeats,
        d.dateid,
        d.trainingDates,
        d.trainingtime,
        c.CourseDescription,
        i.instructorName,
        l.location,
        l.seating_capacity 
FROM    tblLocations l
        INNER JOIN tblCourses c 
            ON l.locationId = c.locationId
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  t.LocationID, t.CourseID, SeatsTaken = COUNT(*)
            FROM    tblTrainings t 
            GROUP BY t.LocationID, t.CourseID
        ) t
            ON l.locationId = t.LocationId 
            AND c.courseId = t.courseId
        INNER JOIN tblTrainingDates d 
            ON c.dateid=d.dateid 
        INNER JOIN tblCourseInstructor ic 
            ON c.courseId = ic.CourseId  
        INNER JOIN tblInstructors i 
            ON ic.instructorId = i.instructorId
WHERE   d.trainingDates >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

JOINs tend to optimise better than correlated subqueries (although sometimes the optimiser can determine that a JOIN would work instead), it also means that you can reference the result (`SeatsTaken`) multiple times without re-evaluating the subquery.

In addition, by moving the count to a subquery, and removing the join to `tblTrainings` I think you eliminate the need for `DISTINCT` which should improve the performance.

Finally I have changed this line:

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d.trainingDates, 101) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
```

To

```
WHERE   d.trainingDates >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

I don't know if you do, but if you had an index on d.TrainingDates then by converting it to varchar to compare it to today you remove the ability for the optimiser to use this index, since you are only saying `>=` midnight today, there is no need to perform any conversion on d.TrainingDates, and all you need to do is remove the time portion of GETDATE(), which can be done by casting to DATE. More on this is contained [in this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) (Yet another gem from [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/))

Comment: et al, please, please forgive me. I didn't post entire code because I thought I could integrate whatever solution I have with the rest of my code but I am having problem doing just that.

I have posted entire query above. 

Could you please help integrate with Gareth's solution?

Very sorry about this.

Comment: Thank you Good LORD for people like you Gareth!

May God Bless you for your patience and assistance.

THANK YOU Sir!!!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid repeating the expression, you can use a [`WITH` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to simplify your query:

```
WITH (
   -- Start with your query that already works
   SELECT DISTINCT l.Seating_Capacity - (select count(*)
                    from tblTrainings t1, tbllocations l
                    where l.locationId = t1.LocationId) AS availableSeats
   FROM tblTrainings t1, tbllocations l
   WHERE l.locationId = t1.LocationId
) AS source
SELECT
    -- Add a CASE statement on top of it
    CASE WHEN availableSeats = 0 THEN 'Full'
    ELSE STR(availableSeats)
    END AS availableSeats
FROM source
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `)` at the end of your case statement remove that.

```
 0 then 'full' else STR(Seating_Capacity) end)
                                            ^^^
```

for `Seating_Capacity` try accessing it with table alias like `l.Seating_Capacity`

Comment: Extraordinarily sensational responses!

You guys are absolutely amazing.

Thank you all very, very much for rescuing me so quickly.

I don't know how to award these points. I would love to check EVERY box.

If there is away to do so, please you experts let me know.

It is working beautifully. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @dasblikenlight,

Your query is very cool but I could not run it. It was giving all sorts of errors. First it has issues with the first `(`. I fixed that and it started giving errors on AS source.